# Ignite Community Edition: Configuring IGFS with HDFS as persistent storage

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, ignite

i would like to have more details about the configuration of apache ignite (cluster igfs) and hdfs. I can't find any official reference, so i doubt that is possibile to do so with the opensource version of apache ignite and i need to switch to something like gridgain. Is that true? I would like to use apache ignite to perform in-memory computation with spark and i would like to have a "kind of automatic" sync with hadoop hdfs as backend storage, because i don't want to perform any manual load from hdfs.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can still use Apache Ignite's integration with Spark to work with HDFS:

https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/extensions-and-integrations/ignite-for-spark/overview#supported-spark-version

There are currently integrations for Spark 2.3, 2.4 and 3.0. The latter was added not so long ago, for some reason it is not in the documentation. But it's here:

https://downloads.apache.org/ignite/ignite-extensions/ignite-spark-ext/3.0.0/

Anyway, you can also check my webinar about this integration:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lkRh2TO8VSU

Also you can see the examples here:

https://github.com/GridGain-Demos/spark-hdfs-ignite-aws-deployment-demo/blob/master/spark_example_project/src/main/java/test/SparkIgniteLoaderFromHdfs.java

Answer (score 1):

Igfs was removed in 2019 to focus on high-performance in-memory computing and querying. The Apache HDFS project is better suited as a file system (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Hadoop#HDFS) .